# XML data does not return URL

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Already put all the possible parameters and data in a URL does not return xml.
the XML locally hosted works, but not with URL.

HTML:

```
<section ng-controller="AppController" class="container-podcastapp">
         <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="guitar in dataSet">
               <div class="resultwrapper">
                   <h2>{{guitar.make}} {{guitar.model}}</h2>
                </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
    </section>
```

javascript and fiddle

Comment: From what domain is the containing HTML page served, and to what domain are you posting?

Comment: was "no, external" meant to be an answer to my question?  I did not ask a yes/no question.

Comment: had not understood, but they are different hosts.

Comment: Cross domain issue - Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: is possible to solve this only being in html?

Answer (score 1):

First your jsfiddle example was not working.
I fixed it for you: http://jsfiddle.net/WhU2d/2/

And now you'll see the problem in console:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://cristianoveloz.com/podcast5/scripts/guitars.xml.
Origin http://fiddle.jshell.net is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

And for this issue you'll find many other entries, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595515/xmlhttprequest-error-origin-null-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin).

Comment: I guy really rushed and I did not even notice, also lacked an external file that converts xml to json. Thanks.
http://jsfiddle.net/WhU2d/3/